How to install Paperproof for Lean 4?
How to install Paperproof for Lean 4 with Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?
I already read https://github.com/Paper-Proof/paperproof?tab=readme-ov-file#readme.
I'm working with Visual Studio Code (VSCode) under Windows.
Where should I type in the commands?
It seems the description fails with the current versions of Lean: we don't have a file lakefile.lean in the project directory anymore.

Try cd lean in the repo? I saw they have two lakefile.lean, one of them is a sample file that doesn't actually build the project

Recently Lean switched to using lakefile.toml by default (link).
So, instead of requiring paperproof from the lakefile.lean file, you should require it from the lakefile.toml file as follows:
[[require]]
name = "Paperproof"
git = "https://github.com/Paper-Proof/paperproof.git"
rev = "main"
subDir = "lean"

